# Expose jar resources over web

Tags: java, spring, resources, jar

I have a web-service (with **Spring-WS**).

I have a jar with several schemas (schema1.xsd, schema2.xsd and schema3.xsd) which I include in my web service.

Is there a way to expose the schemas from the jar through a servlet somehow in my web-service wep app?

My Spring `MessageDispatcherServlet` is mapped to /ws/

I would like my schemas to be exposed to `/schemas/schema1.xsd` `/schemas/schema2.xsd` and so on.

I have an idea how to do it with a servlet, but it's too verbose and there has to be a nicer way.

The way I am thinking is have a servlet filter and everything that hits /schemas/ check if it is in my list of allowed resources and display it.

This has to be a server agnostic solution. (For instance http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/ will not work).

Thanks.

Comment: Be careful - your resources in WEB-INF/ are protected for a reason. If you build a truly generic solution (which would be slick), you may inadvertantly provide access to any resource in WEB-INF/. Not a bad thing necessarily, but you take this into consideration and consider if and how to limit access to only those resources you intend to serve.

Comment: Spring-WS has nice support for auto-generating a WSDL file based on your schemas, and being able to serve the wsdl. This will by it's nature include the definitions from your xsd files. Are you using this?

Comment: Wsdl11Definition will use the xsd's just fine. The problem is not in the wsdl, but in the availability of the xsd's. Per say if I want to use SoapUI giving it the wsdl it will fail to load because it will try to load all the xsd's and they will not be there

Comment: See my 2nd answer for an alternative solution to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me again!  Having seen the comments to your original question, I thought I'd offer an alternative solution.

If I understand your problem, it seems you have a WSDL (generated by Spring-WS) which contains references to the various schema. When a client tries to follow those schema references, it fails, because there is no such resource.

Spring-WS offers a nice way out of this, which is described in the [section on WSDL exposure](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/server.html#server-automatic-wsdl-exposure):

> If you want to use multiple schemas,
>   either by includes or imports, you
>   might want to use the
>   CommonsXsdSchemaCollection, and refer
>   to that from the
>   DefaultWsdl11Definition, like so:

```
<bean id="schemaCollection" class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaCollection">
    <property name="xsds">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/path/to/schema1.xsd</value>
            <value>classpath:/path/to/schema2.xsd</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="inline" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

> When the inline property is enabled,
>   it follows all XSD imports and
>   includes, and inlines them in the
>   WSDL. This greatly simplifies the
>   deloyment of the schemas, which still
>   making it possible to edit them
>   separately.

So what you get is a generated WSDL with all of the referenced schemas inlined, so there *are* no references for the client to follow.  It's very slick, and means you don't have to expose your schema files individually.

Comment: Waw! That's what I need.
Thanks a million, I should read more :)

Answer (score 2):

They only way I've found to do this in the past is the have a Spring controller (or servlet, whatever's your poison), which opens a stream to the resource in the JAR (using `Class.getResourceAsStream`, for example), and then "piping" it to the HTTP response (using Apache Commons IO's `IOUtils.copy()`).

It's not very nice, but it's a fully generic solution (just parameterise it with the classpath of the resource).

Here's my source for this:

```
@Controller
public class ResourceController {

    private Resource resource;

    @Required
    public void setResource(Resource resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    @RequestMapping
    public void handleRequest(HttpServletResponse httpResponse) throws IOException {
        InputStream resourceStream = resource.getInputStream();
        try {
            IOUtils.copy(resourceStream, httpResponse.getOutputStream());
        } finally {
            resourceStream.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I did the same thing with a servlet.
For security purposes I need to define the list of xsd's I will allow. I do that via init parameters.
Still this solution seems to me to be a hack. I thought there has to be a easier way, a Spring way, but I guess because of security issues it might cause, nobody actually implement any solutions.

Comment: It feels like a hack, yes, but then the contents of JAR files (and things under `/WEB-INF`) are not *supposed* to be accessible via the client, so you have to go the extra mile.

Comment: Apparently there is a simpler solution in Servlet 3.0, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732965/exposing-resources-from-jar-files-in-web-applications-tomcat7.

Answer (score 0):

Just package your XSD's in a war called schemas.war, put in a default web.xml, and deploy the war in whatever web container you use. Its the easiest, code-less way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this isn't exactly an "answer" but need 4 more points before I can post a comment. I wanted to get it out here though, and maybe save someone else a lot of the trouble that I just went through.

I discovered that if you only have one xsd, it will get merged into the wsdl when using just the DefaultWsdl11Definition but if you use an `<sws:dynamic-wsdl>` block to generate the wsdl it just creates a reference to the xsd file which may or may not be what you want. It didn't work for me when trying to use a .NET client to hit the service.