# Create a war containing only image

Tags: image, url, maven, resources, war

I'm trying to create a war that is to be deployed in an EAR and that should contain only images.

My war source organization is as follows :

```
+---src
|   +---main
|   |   +---java
|   |   +---resources
|   |   |   \---META-INF
|   |   |       \---resources
|   |   |           \---images
|   |   |                   placeholder_image.jpg
|   |   |                   placeholder_template.png
|   |   |
|   |   \---webapp
|   |       \---WEB-INF
|   \---test
|       +---java
|       \---resources
```

and my war effective organization is

```
+---META-INF
\---WEB-INF
    \---classes
        \---META-INF
            \---resources
                \---images
                        placeholder_image.jpg
                        placeholder_template.png
```

The images I want to serve are in the `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/images` folder.

I package this war using maven-war-plugin.

Under which url will those images be available on my local machine, provided my war is indicated as available under the `http://localhost:8080/myapp/` path ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None. Content from WEB-INF is not statically served, `resources` is for classpath resources. You need to put the images (folder) directly under `webapp` or add an servlet that serves the content.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on whether you deploy the `war` in a Servlet-3-compatible container like Tomcat 7 or Jetty 8.

If so, your resources should be visible under `http://localhost:8080/myapp/images/...`.

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732965/exposing-resources-from-jar-files-in-web-applications-tomcat7), where the only difference is that the resources are packaged in a `jar`. For `jar`s, this feature makes more sense than for `WEB-INF/classes`, as, like the first answer  points out, you should simply put your resources directly into `src/main/webapp` if they are located in the same Maven module.