# accessing web resources from jar

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-4.2.x, webresource

i am trying to place my web resources in a jar insetad of putting them at the roor dir of the war file. So i followed the post [Exposing resources from jar files in web applications (Tomcat7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732965/exposing-resources-from-jar-files-in-web-applications-tomcat7)
and placed all my rsources under resources dir, but still i couldnt access. The only diffrenece is that i am using JBoss4.2.2GA.
I am accessing my resources as

http://localhost:18080/webapp/Email.png

another thing, can i put my jsps as well in META-INF/resources dir of my jar from lib dir?

Comment: where is the code that looks this up

Comment: war/WEB-INF/lib/foo.jar. All resources like images,css,js are under foo.jar/META-INF/resources dir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://community.jboss.org/wiki/VersionOfTomcatInJBossAS.

JBoss AS 4.2.2.GA includes JBoss Web 2.0.1 based on Tomcat 6.0.13 which didn't yet support this feature and Servlet 3.0 API.