# Generic War file just like API concept

Tags: java, api, jakarta-ee

AS you may know that when an API is prepared, it can be used in any project just by adding it into classpath in J2SE. I wonder if it is possible to create a web page and compiled it into a war file just like an API definition so that It can directly be used within an ear.

Comment: "API" doesn't indicate any formal construct. Perhaps you could tell us in more detail what it is that you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that using a war file, because a war file would define a new web application separated from the other ones.

But since the servlet 3.0 spec, you can do that with a jar file placed in the WEB-INF/lib directory of your war file, using the META-INF/resources directory of the jar. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732965/exposing-resources-from-jar-files-in-web-applications-tomcat7) for details.