# Return JavaScript as static resource from a Jar archive

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, webresource

Is there a way to return JavaScript that is located in a .jar archive? At the moment I have the following structure:

```
webapp
   resources
        scripts
           SomeJavaScript.js
           ...
```

List of such .js files is very large. And there is a .jar file that has all such files.

In Spring config files I have:

```
  <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
```

To process all static resources by my dispatcher servlet. But, I'd like it to read the JavaScript files from the .jar archive.  What's the easiest way to do that?

I think writing my own controller for such purpose would not be the best option.

PS: I've found the [following solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732965/exposing-resources-from-jar-files-in-web-applications-tomcat7):

I'm using embedded Tomcat 7, starting it using Maven plugin.
Here's [mentioned](https://blogs.oracle.com/alexismp/entry/web_inf_lib_jar_meta) that resource files need to be under `WEB-INF/lib/{\*.jar}/META-INF/resources` but looking inside `spring-js-resources.jar`, the actual location is `WEB-INF/lib/{\*.jar}/META-INF/web-resources`. The generated page contains links like these:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SomeProjectName/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

And this file is not available. What can I do to resolve the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `mvc:resources` tag to expose contents of .jar files on the classpath by adding a `classpath:` path to the `locations` attribute.

I believe in your case it would be something like

```
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/"/>
```

More information in [Spring MVC documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources).

Comment: I've read the documentation, and I agree with you, that it should help, but it doesn't. Also, I deployed war file into the tomcat 7 webapps (not embeddable one) but it did not help either.

Comment: Actually it helped! I've forgotten to update my url in jsp pages. I set it as: <spring:url value="/resources/spring/Spring.js" var="springJs"/> and it helped!!!! Thank  you very much for your reply. I'm really tired to fight with spring, maven, etc and its configuration. Not development. Only configuration wars:(

Comment: Yeah, I agree path-related problems are one of the most frustrating; perhaps setting Spring's logging level to DEBUG/TRACE would help? It usually prints all tried locations one by one.