# WAR - JSPs and resources inside jar library?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jar, war

I'm creating a Java EE web application and I need to design it in a modular way. My idea was to create the core .war package and in case of need add some modules as it's .jar libraries. My question is: Can i put for example html, jsp, css etc. inside the jar bundled with .war and how can I access them from the .war?

For example if the customer needs a discussion forum, I'd like to add the .jar module including all required JSPs, CSS and so on and make it accessible like

```
http://my-web.com/forum/index.jsp
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a plugin mechanism for your application server. You may want to check out Apache Felix or other OSGI implementations and embed them in your application server. You can then later add osgi bundles as plugins to your system.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I've found this thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732965/exposing-resources-from-jar-files-in-web-applications-tomcat7) which looks like something I'm looking for. I think that OSGI or Felix is too big overkill for my app.