# Serving GWT Dependency in .war Project

Tags: maven, servlets, gwt, libgdx, war

What is the 'best' way of serving compiled GWT *stuff* in a separate .war project?

I am working on a LibGDX game with backend web services. At the moment I have a single .war project that has HTTP endpoints for the web services, and is also doubling up to serve the HTML UI (welcome pages, static content).

I would like the contents of my Maven GWT module to magically appear where Tomcat can serve them in my .war project.

Should I be using a war overlay (I'm not really sure what one is)? Should I use `maven-assembly-plugin` to unpack GWT bits into the `src/main/webapp/` directory of my .war project? Should I co-erce the GWT module to compile its stuff to the `META-INF/resources` directory of its jar, where [Servlet 3.0 containers can serve it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732965/exposing-resources-from-jar-files-in-web-applications-tomcat7) from? Is there a preferred approach?

Comment: You have a working buildprocess which creates one waer archive, but you want to create a second war file with the static content, right?

Comment: Thanks for reading. I don't want the module that compiles the GWT stuff to be a .war project really, as I won't ever serve it on its own, so at the moment it is a .jar.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a WAR-project and simply want to add the compiled GWT stuff as static files to that project, I would suggest to use the assembly-plugin.

Take a look at this two files:

[pom.xml](https://github.com/dankurka/mgwt.showcase/blob/master/pom.xml)
[clientcode.xml](https://github.com/dankurka/mgwt.showcase/blob/master/src/main/assembly/clientcode.xml)

This will create a ZIP-file with the compiled GWT client as a ZIP file.

In you WAR-project you can download and unzip this artifact in the process-resources phase.