# Maven module for static files

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a web application with spring and maven. The application is divided into maven modules. I have an "application-web" module that generates war. Another "application-ear" module that generates an ear. And another "application-static" with css, js and images that generates a zip file.

This would be the outline of my application:

- application

  - application-web (java code)
  - application-ear
  - application-static (css, js and images)
  - application-resources (language properties)

I want to deploy the eclipse use files of "static" module, instead of using the files in the "application/src/main/webapp" directory. How can I do this? It is possible?

Comment: Why have you move the css/js and images into application-static instead directly into application-web module?

Comment: These are the specifications of the project. A module for static files, one for internationalization messages and another for configuration files settings.

Comment: This works but I have another problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't waste your time with unpacking resources, everything works out of the box:

1. Resource bundles: the are always loaded from the classpath, regardlessly it is exploded (`WEB-INF/classes`) or compressed (`WEB-INF/lib`)
2. Serving static resources: bundle them up in a JAR and use either Tomcat (Servlet 3.0) feature to serve from `META-INF/resources`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4733048/696632) or use Spring's built in [`mvc:resources`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources) element.

Simply add the dependency snippets in your WAR POM and your are done.

Comment: I have the application-static dependecy in the application-web pom and remove de build secction. I remove the static files of src/main/webapp directory. How to get the static files with mvc: resources? Before I use <mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/assets/" /> because the files was in application-web module.

Comment: @oscar `location` is using default resource paths applied in Spring. I.e., since you are in a webapp default locations are resolved agaist the webapp, to get resources from JARs, use `classpath:/assets/`.

Comment: Not working for me, the application-static module generate a zip not a jar. To deploy in eclipse the static files not found. Inside application-web war not found the zip or static files.

Comment: @oscar Use a standard JAR and it will work. It doesn't make any sense in this environment to use ZIP files.

Comment: If use jar file, the file(application-static.jar) is copy to WEB-INF/lib directory but not find the static files. thanks your patience i`m a noob with maven and packing modules.

Comment: @oscar Show your Spring config.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the maven dependency plugin to unpack your static resources included in the zip file using the following:

In your application-web.pom

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack-resources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>resources</outputDirectory>
                <includeArtifactIds>application-static</includeArtifactIds>
                <includeGroupIds>your group id</includeGroupIds>
                <includes>**/*.js,**/*.css</includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin
```

Comment: I have done this already. I have the zip file. But i don´t know how to put the zip file in the application-web to use it. It is the first time I do something like this.

Comment: I see what you mean. You can use maven-dependency plugin as mentioned above

Comment: Thanks, looks like a good solution. Tomorrow I try it and discuss the results

Comment: @oscar It is not, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This work:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludeTypes>pom</excludeTypes>
                        <includeArtifactIds>application-static</includeArtifactIds>
                        <includeGroupIds>com.foo.foo.application</includeGroupIds>
                        <outputDirectory>src/main/webapp</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
</build>
```

But I have another problem, with this solution only copy the static files when I execute clean package. If I run the application-web with eclipse and I do changes in a js file in application-static, the changes have no effect until I execute clean package. Any solution for this?