# Where to put static file in Maven project

Tags: java, file, maven

I have created a simple Maven project with no archetype, everything is okay. Then I added a `CVA.pmml` file under the `main/resources` directory. Afterwards, I want to read the file but get `FileNotFoundException`. I tried the following methods:

Method 1:

```
InputStream is = BundleTest.class.getResourceAsStream("CVA.pmml");
```

Method 2:

```
InputStream is = BundleTest.class.getResourceAsStream("resources/CVA.pmml");
```

Method 3:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("CVA.pmml");
```

Method 4:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("resources/CVA.pmml");
```

None of them works. Any suggestion?

Here is the screenshot of the project structure:

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: Can you provide us a screen shot of the workspace? Just want to see the folder structure

Comment: Possible duplicate [Maven module for static files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209890/maven-module-for-static-files)

Comment: Can you try with InputStream is = new FileInputStream("./CVA.pmml");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Method 1:
>
> ```
> InputStream is = BundleTest.class.getResourceAsStream("CVA.pmml");
> ```

That will look for the CVA.pmml resource in the same package as the BundleTest class. But CVA.pmml is in the root package, whereas BundleTest is not.

> Method 2:
>
> ```
> InputStream is = BundleTest.class.getResourceAsStream("resources/CVA.pmml");
> ```

That will look for it in the resources package under the package of the BundleTest class. But it's in the root package.

> Method 3:
>
> ```
> InputStream is = new FileInputStream("CVA.pmml");
> ```

That wil look it on the file system, in the directory from which you executed the java command. But it's in the classpath, embedded in the jar (or in a classpath directory)

> Method 4:
>
> ```
> InputStream is = new FileInputStream("resources/CVA.pmml");
> ```

That wil look it on the file system, in the directory `resources, under the directory from which you executed the java command. But it's in the classpath, embedded in the jar (or in a classpath directory)

The correct way is

```
InputStream is = BundleTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/CVA.pmml");
```

(notice the leading slash)

or

```
InputStream is = BundleTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("CVA.pmml");
```

Comment: Works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -2):

Create a folder named static inside resources folder and put your files there .  And access it like this "/CVA.pmml"