# javax.mail how to attach a image folder java project

Tags: java, image, email, jakarta-mail, attachment

I work with javax.mail.

The project structure is

[image]

I want to attach to the body the mail the image in project path

```
resources/imgecalcp/fondoencabezado_marron.png
```

My code is

```
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                             new InternetAddress(to));
msg.setSubject(subject,"UTF-8");
MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");
MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
htmlFinal = ConversionTools.convertTypeHTML(body);
messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlFinal, "text/html");
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart.attachFile("resources/imgecalcp/fondoencabezado_marron.png");
messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image>");
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
msg.setContent(multipart);
Transport.send(msg);
```

I get the exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources\imgecalcp\fondoencabezado_marron.png (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at javax.activation.FileDataSource.getInputStream(FileDataSource.java:82)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:290)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1403)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:874)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:444)
    at com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed.writeTo(multipart_mixed.java:102)
    at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:869)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:302)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1403)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1745)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:636)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:189)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
    at eusurvey.tools.MailSender.run(MailSender.java:172)
    at eusurvey.tools.MailSender$$FastClassByCGLIB$$280bfa43.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:701)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:634)
    at eusurvey.tools.MailSender$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f6b68da0.run(<generated>)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2017-04-28 07:58:06-77048 [Thread-69] (MailSender.java:176) INFO  eusurvey.tools.MailSender  - MailSender.- run .- MessagingException send failed, exception: IOException while sending message
javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources\imgecalcp\fondoencabezado_marron.png (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:676)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:189)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
    at eusurvey.tools.MailSender.run(MailSender.java:172)
    at eusurvey.tools.MailSender$$FastClassByCGLIB$$280bfa43.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:701)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:634)
    at eusurvey.tools.MailSender$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f6b68da0.run(<generated>)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources\imgecalcp\fondoencabezado_marron.png (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at javax.activation.FileDataSource.getInputStream(FileDataSource.java:82)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:290)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1403)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:874)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:444)
    at com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed.writeTo(multipart_mixed.java:102)
    at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:869)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:302)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1403)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1745)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:636)
    ... 16 more
354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources\imgecalcp\fondoencabezado_marron.png (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)
javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources\imgecalcp\fondoencabezado_marron.png (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:676)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:189)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
    at eusurvey.tools.MailSender.run(MailSender.java:172)
    at eusurvey.tools.MailSender$$FastClassByCGLIB$$280bfa43.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:701)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:634)
    at eusurvey.tools.MailSender$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f6b68da0.run(<generated>)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

How can I attach the image that is in resources folder project?

Comment: there is no resources folder after packageing

Comment: Seems like a duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/q/43672502/227775. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Get path of resource folder of by `classLoader.getResource()` and inside `getResource()` you can pass relative path from resource folder.

```
messageBodyPart.attachFile(new File(classLoader.getResource("imgecalcp/fondoencabezado_marron.png").getFile()));
```

Comment: Please include more context/explanation for the code to make the answer more useful.

Comment: This doesn't work with Spring running as JAR. It will throw something like: class path resource [image.jpg] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system jar:file:// ...